# substring of a string and print it out

Tags: c, string, substring, strtok, strncpy

I want to disect the following string:

```
char msg[30] ="Hello 13 1";
char *psh;
int num1;
int num2;
char s[30],s[30];
```

i try this but:

```
pch = strtok (msg," ");
while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
   }
```

which outputs:

```
 Hello
 13
 1
```

I just want to make the number '13' equal to num1, number '1' equal to num2:

```
    printf("%d\n",num1);

    Output: 13


    printf("%d\n",num2);

    Output: 1
```

I try:

```
 sscanf(sc, "%s %d %d", &s, &num1, &num2);
```

which outputs:

```
 Segmentation fault
```

thanks

[EDIT]

```
 char * pch
 char s[30];
char sc[30];
char num1[30];
char num2[30];



 pch = strtok (s," ");
 while (pch != NULL)
 {
   printf ("%s\n",pch);
   pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
 } 

 sscanf(sc, "%s %d %d", pch, &num1, &num2);
```

Comment: Don't use the address-of operator (`&`) for strings, they already are pointers (or decay to pointers in the case of arrays).

Comment: And if you have never tried to use a debugger before, now is the perfect time to do. If you run your program in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash. You can then look at the function call stack, and even walk up the call stack so you end up at your code (if you're not there already) and then examine the values of variables. At the wery least, please build with debug information (add the `-g` flag to `gcc`) and run in a debugger and edit the question to include the output of the `bt` debugger command (which shows the function call stack, a.k.a. a back-trace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) function:

```
sscanf(msg, "%s %d %d", s, &num1, &num2);
```

Which would result in your code looking something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char msg[30] = "Hello 13 1";
    int num1, num2;
    char s[30];
    sscanf(msg, "%s %d %d", s, &num1, &num2);
    printf("%d\n%d\n", num1, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value of `sscanf()` before relying on the variables having proper values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the code

```
pch = strtok (s," ");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
} 

sscanf(sc, "%s %d %d", pch, &num1, &num2);
```

then you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because you attempt to write to a `NULL` pointer.

After the loop, `pch` will be `NULL`.

Also, `num1` and `num2` are arrays of characters (e.g. strings), but you try to extract the numbers as integers. While the arrays are big enough to fit the integer values, it's still wrong if you want them as actual integers.

You should also take note that [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) modifies the input string.